# Linear maps (complex)

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]$(1)$ Let $a, b\in \mathbb C$ and $\alpha: \mathbb C^2 \to \mathbb C$ be given by $(x, y)\mapsto ax + by.$

$\quad(a)\quad$ Show that $\alpha$ is a $\mathbb C$- linear map. What condition(s) you have to check?

$\quad(b)\quad$ For what values of $a$ and $b$ is $\alpha$ surjective? Justify your answer.

$\quad (c)\quad$ Find a basis for $\operatorname{ker}\alpha$. Justify your answer. The answer will depend on $a$ and $b$.

Can anyone help me? 
I think I got the 1. a) but don't really get linear maps.

Comment: So we can help you with respect to understanding linear maps, it would help if you include what you "got" for $1.a$, so we can confirm, or correct your work, and go from there.

Comment: I added a photo of my 1.a)

Comment: mrHarry: Great! Thanks for responding!

Comment: Yeah, but don't know what to do next. or is this right at least?

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

For **any** linear space $\;V_{\Bbb F}\;$ over a field, we have that a linear functional $\;f:V\to\Bbb F\;$ is either the zero function or automatically surjective, because of the dimensions theorem:

$$\dim_{\Bbb F} V=\dim\ker f+\dim\text{Im}\,f$$

and taking into account that $\;0\le\dim\text{Im}\,f\le 1\;$ ...

In your case, $\;V=\Bbb C^2_{\Bbb C}\;\;,\;\;\Bbb F=\Bbb C\;$ and etc.